# Is it possible to pass a App setting in the web.config to a Common C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Is it possible to pass a App setting "string" in the web.config to a Common C# class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it's possible - but the thing to keep in mind is that a properly designed class (unless it's explicitly designed for ASP.NET) shouldn't know or care where the information comes from. There should be a property (or method, but properties are the more '.NET way' of doing things) that you set with the string value from the application itself, rather than having the class directly grab information from web.config.

Comment: Good answer! Wish I hadn't already used up today's votes. Properties are definitely the way to do this properly.

Comment: Agreed. The application plumbing/control code can access the config file freely, but business classes should not. Missing config keys is a run time error, so if a developer uses a class that expects the config file to be there in a 2nd project, they may not see the error until it's in production.

Answer (score 10):

In any class you can use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyToSetting"]` to access any value in the  element of web.config (or app.config)

Comment: This works, but isn't always good design. See Harper Shelby's answer and its comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configuration values that are used in many places consider developing a Configuration class that abstracts the actual loading of the configuration items and provides strongly typed values and conversions, and potentially default values.

This technique localizes access to the configuration file making it easy to switch implementations later (say store in registry instead) and makes it so the values only have to be read from the file once -- although, I would hope that the configuration manager would be implemented this way as well and read all values the first time it is used and provide them from an internal store on subsequent accesses.  The real benefit is strong typing and one-time-only conversions, I think.

```
public static class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    private static DateTime myEpoch;
    public static DateTime Epoch
    {
       get
       {
          if (myEpoch == null)
          {
              string startEpoch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Epoch"];
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startEpoch))
              {
                 myEpoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
              }
              else
              {
                 myEpoch = DateTime.Parse(startEpoch);
              }
          }
          return myEpoch;   
       }
    }
}
```